# Swift make containerStackView scrollable

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to make my StackView scrollable left and right. I currently make the view by using the following code:

```
let containerStackView = UIStackView()
    
    let verticalStackView = UIStackView()
    let verticalViewOne = UIView()
    let verticalViewTwo = UIView()
    let verticalViewThree = UIView()
func setupViews(){
            verticalStackView.axis = .horizontal
            verticalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            verticalStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
            
            //verticalViewOne.backgroundColor = .red
            //containerStackView.backgroundColor = .green
            //verticalViewTwo.backgroundColor = .black
            
            containerStackView.axis = .vertical
            containerStackView.spacing = 0
            containerStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        }
        
        func setupHierachy(){
            view.addSubview(containerStackView)
            view.addSubview(verticalStackView)
            
            verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalViewOne)
            verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalViewTwo)
            verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalViewThree)
            verticalViewOne.addSubview(DRN1Button)
            verticalViewTwo.addSubview(LIFEButton)
            verticalViewThree.addSubview(PERTHRadioButton)
            //verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(DRN1Button)
            containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalStackView)
            
            
        }
        
        func setlayout(){
            containerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            containerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            containerStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
            containerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            containerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            
            DRN1Button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            DRN1Button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.topAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
            DRN1Button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
            DRN1Button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            DRN1Button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            
            LIFEButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            LIFEButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.topAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
            LIFEButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
            LIFEButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
            LIFEButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            LIFEButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            
            PERTHRadioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            PERTHRadioButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.topAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
            PERTHRadioButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
            PERTHRadioButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
            PERTHRadioButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            PERTHRadioButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        }
```

I am wondering what would I need to add to make it scrollable left and right as I want to add more then 3 vertical views

UPDATE

I tried to put it into a scrollView but it keeps crashing now

```
"UIScrollView:0x10286f200.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Here is the code.

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
 func setupViews(){
    verticalStackView.axis = .horizontal
    verticalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    verticalStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    
    //verticalViewOne.backgroundColor = .red
    //containerStackView.backgroundColor = .green
    //verticalViewTwo.backgroundColor = .black
    
    containerStackView.axis = .vertical
    containerStackView.spacing = 0
    containerStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
}

func setupHierachy(){
    scrollView.addSubview(verticalStackView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    //view.addSubview(containerStackView)
   //view.addSubview(verticalStackView)
    
    
    
    verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalViewOne)
    verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalViewTwo)
    verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalViewThree)
    verticalViewOne.addSubview(DRN1Button)
    verticalViewTwo.addSubview(LIFEButton)
    verticalViewThree.addSubview(PERTHRadioButton)
    //verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(DRN1Button)
    //containerStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalStackView)
    
    
}

func setlayout(){
    //containerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //containerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    //containerStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
    //containerStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    //containerStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
    verticalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    verticalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    verticalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    verticalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    verticalStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
  
    
    DRN1Button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    DRN1Button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.topAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
    DRN1Button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    DRN1Button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    DRN1Button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewOne.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    LIFEButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    LIFEButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.topAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
    LIFEButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    LIFEButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    LIFEButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    LIFEButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewTwo.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    PERTHRadioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    PERTHRadioButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.topAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
    PERTHRadioButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    PERTHRadioButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    PERTHRadioButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    PERTHRadioButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: verticalViewThree.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: place stackview inside scrollview

Comment: @Babar I did and it crashing